# Handler for Request not found: ServiceStack, IIS7, and bundled css images

Tags: css, servicestack, bundling-and-minification

I used the standard bundling supplied with MVC to bundle and minify my .css files. This process involves creating virtual directories (actual virtual directories that don't exist physically on the drive, not the virtual directory concept that IIS uses).

When running ServiceStack, everything works (all pages load including images) **except** for the images that are served from the *virtual directory of my bundled/minified css*.

Here's the error I receive

```
Handler for Request not found: 


Request.ApplicationPath: /
Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath: /img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png
Request.FilePath: /img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png
Request.HttpMethod: GET
Request.MapPath('~'): C:\inetpub\TR.net\
Request.Path: /img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png
Request.PathInfo: 
Request.ResolvedPathInfo: /img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png
Request.PhysicalPath: C:\inetpub\TR.net\img\glyphicons-halflings-white.png
Request.PhysicalApplicationPath: C:\inetpub\TR.net\
Request.QueryString: 
Request.RawUrl: /img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png
Request.Url.AbsoluteUri: https://tr.net/img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png
Request.Url.AbsolutePath: /img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png
Request.Url.Fragment: 
Request.Url.Host: tr.net
Request.Url.LocalPath: /img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png
Request.Url.Port: 443
Request.Url.Query: 
Request.Url.Scheme: https
Request.Url.Segments: System.String[]
App.IsIntegratedPipeline: True
App.WebHostPhysicalPath: C:\inetpub\TR.net
App.WebHostRootFileNames: [global.asax,hello.cshtml,packages.config,web.config,aspnet_client,assets,bin,bundles,properties,views]
App.DefaultHandler: /Home
App.DebugLastHandlerArgs: GET|/img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png|C:\inetpub\TR.net\img\glyphicons-halflings-white.png
```

My web.config is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>    
  <system.web>
<pages validateRequest="false"></pages>
<compilation targetFramework="4.5">
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".cshtml" type="ServiceStack.Razor.CSharpRazorBuildProvider, ServiceStack.Razor" />
  </buildProviders>      
    </compilation>
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="ServiceStack.Factory" path="*" verb="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="true" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webPages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="ServiceStack.Html" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack.Razor" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack.Text" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack.OrmLite" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

I found a user with [a similar problem here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/servicestack/d5-2wEPQZjI) and his solution was as follows:

> Static files not in a virtual directory weren't being served because the app pool identity didn't have permission to read the file.
>   Static files that were contained in a virtual directory weren't being served because the ServiceStack handler was servicing the request, which I didn't expect to happen. I had to remove the service stack handler for the virtual directory.

However, I have no idea how to perform what he described.

Can anyone assist with this?